# How to retrieve whole object from cache memory without skipping some records

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, caching, razor

I'm using ASP.NET MVC3 with razor engine.
I am working on online shopping application. In this application I've stored object into cache memory. But when I try to retrieve an object from cached, its skipping some records when I apply a filter on this object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you filter the **same object** that is in the cache. Therefore you need to clone your object. The way you clone it depends on what kind of object it is. Then you apply the filter to the clone and use the clone as your data source  in that particular request.

Comment: is there any alternative way to prevent this type problem.